# How to Override Standard Event Save button

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

I have one requirement where on click of Save button on event page it should remain in event detail page.
As of now if we create event from any where like Account then after saving it, it will go back to previous page i.e. Account.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need Visualforce to do this. You cannot do it by somehow configuring the standard interface.

An example on how to achieve this (not only with Events, but with any object) is below.

Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="theExtension">

<apex:form>
  <apex:inputField value="{!myEvent.Subject}" />
<!-- Add All the fields you want here, possibly adding formatting as well>

  <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" />
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Class

```
public class theExtension {
   private final Event myEvent;

  public theExtension(ApexPages.StandardControllers stdCtr) {
    this.myEvent = (Event)stdCtr.getRecord();
  }

  public PageReference save() {
    upsert myEvent;

    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes I am agree with @Sebastian